# TO_CHAR function not available in H2 database

Tags: java, h2

I am using H2 database for integration test. The code is quiet old and is using JDBC queries instead.

While running tests i am getting the error below

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Function "TO_CHAR" not found; SQL statement:
```

I can see that H2 does not implecitely supports TO_CHAR function. Is there any way to add a custom methor or should i think about moving to HSQL DB or any other database for testing purpose.

Answer (score 5):

Use the newer version 1.3.175. Since 2014-01-18 available with a [`TO_CHAR`](http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html#to_char) function.

Answer (score 0):

You could try HSQLDB of course. I think it does support TO_CHAR.

Or you could [write a user defined function](http://h2database.com/html/features.html#user_defined_functions) in H2.