# org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Function "TO_CHAR" not found

Tags: sql, database, oracle

org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Function "TO_CHAR" not found; SQL statement:
I am using oracle 12c database and spring java framework.
But this question is related oracle database.
this is sql query.

```
select  c1.kco as CMPY
        ,ltrim(to_char(c1.kco))||' - '||c1.name as DESCR
        ,' ' as IS_DUMMY
        ,'B:Balance Sheet:P:Profit and Loss:R:Revenue:C:Cost' ACCTYPES
        ,nullif('1','1') HIERTYPES
from    pub.mncompany c1
        ,pub.oa_companies c2
where   c1.kco = c2.company
and     c1.del <> 1
and     c2.del <> 1
and     c2.maxPer <> 0
order   by c1.kco
```

how can I fix this error?
Please help me.
thanks.
this is my code.

```
public EntityList getCompanies(String sql) throws SQLException {
    if (_log.isDebugEnabled())
        _log.debug(sql);
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    try {
        stmt = getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);
        stmt.setFetchSize(500);
        resultSet = stmt.executeQuery();
        return JdbcUtils.extractToEntityListImpl(ExternalSystemDAO.COMPANIES_COL_INFO, resultSet);
    } finally {
        closeResultSet(resultSet);
        closeStatement(stmt);
        closeConnection();
    }
}
```

this is getConnection function.

```
/*     */   public Connection getConnection()
/*     */   {
/*  88 */     if (this.mConnection != null) {
/*  89 */       return this.mConnection;
/*     */     }
/*     */     try
/*     */     {
/*  93 */       if (this.mDataSource != null) {
/*  94 */         this.mConnection = this.mDataSource.getConnection();
/*     */       }
/*     */     }
/*     */     catch (SQLException sqle)
/*     */     {
/*  99 */       throw new RuntimeException(sqle.getMessage(), sqle);
/*     */     }
/* 101 */     return this.mConnection;
/*     */   }
```

this is absractDAO.java.

```
/*     */ package com.cedar.cp.ejb.impl.base;
/*     */ 
/*     */ import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.ejb.EntityContext;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import oracle.sql.BLOB;
import oracle.sql.CLOB;

import org.antlr.stringtemplate.StringTemplate;
import org.antlr.stringtemplate.StringTemplateGroup;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;

import com.cedar.cp.api.base.CPException;
import com.cedar.cp.dto.base.PrimaryKey;
import com.cedar.cp.util.Log;
/*     */

import cppro.conn.OracleConnUtils; 

/*     */ public abstract class AbstractDAO
/*     */   implements Serializable
/*     */ {
/* 516 */   protected transient Log _log = new Log(getClass());
/*     */   protected transient DataSource mDataSource;
/*     */   protected transient EntityContext mEntityContext;
/*     */   protected transient Connection mConnection;
/*     */   protected transient long mTimer;
/*     */   protected transient StringTemplateGroup mStringTemplateGroup;
/*     */ 
/*     */   public AbstractDAO()
/*     */   {
/*  29 */     String lookupName = "java:jdbc/fc";
/*     */     try
/*     */     {
/*  32 */       InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
                this.mDataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

                try{
                    ((DriverManagerDataSource) this.mDataSource).setDriverClassName(OracleConnUtils.className);
                    ((AbstractDriverBasedDataSource) this.mDataSource).setUrl(OracleConnUtils.connectionURL);
                    ((AbstractDriverBasedDataSource) this.mDataSource).setUsername(OracleConnUtils.userName);
                    ((AbstractDriverBasedDataSource) this.mDataSource).setPassword(OracleConnUtils.password);

                }catch(Exception ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

///*  33 */       this.mDataSource = ((DataSource)ic.lookup(lookupName));
/*     */     }
/*     */     catch (NamingException ne)
/*     */     {
/*  37 */       throw new RuntimeException("error looking up DataSource " + lookupName + ": " + ne.getMessage(), ne);
/*     */     }
/*     */   }
/*     */ 
/*     */   public AbstractDAO(Connection connection)
/*     */   {
/*  48 */     this.mConnection = connection;
/*     */ 
/*  50 */     this.mDataSource = null;
/*     */   }
/*     */ 
/*     */   public AbstractDAO(DataSource ds)
/*     */   {
/*  59 */     this.mDataSource = ds;
/*     */   }
/*     */ 
/*     */   public AbstractDAO(AbstractDAO abstractDAO)
/*     */   {
/*  68 */     if (abstractDAO.getDataSource() != null)
/*  69 */       this.mDataSource = abstractDAO.getDataSource();
/*     */     else
/*  71 */       this.mConnection = abstractDAO.getConnection();
/*     */   }
/*     */ 
/*     */   public DataSource getDataSource()
/*     */   {
/*  80 */     return this.mDataSource;
/*     */   }
/*     */ 
/*     */   public Connection getConnection()
/*     */   {
/*  88 */     if (this.mConnection != null) {
/*  89 */       return this.mConnection;
/*     */     }
/*     */     try
/*     */     {
/*  93 */       if (this.mDataSource != null) {
/*  94 */         this.mConnection = this.mDataSource.getConnection();
/*     */       }
/*     */     }
/*     */     catch (SQLException sqle)
/*     */     {
/*  99 */       throw new RuntimeException(sqle.getMessage(), sqle);
/*     */     }
/* 101 */     return this.mConnection;
/*     */   }

    /**
     * @throws SQLException
     */
    public static void startOracleDebugger(Connection concection) {
        // Connect to SQL Developer listenning on localhost:4000
        if (Boolean.getBoolean("oracle.debug")) {
            try {
                CallableStatement cs = concection
                        .prepareCall("{CALL DBMS_DEBUG_JDWP.CONNECT_TCP(?,?)}");
                cs.setString(1, "localhost");
                cs.setString(2, "4000");
                cs.execute();
                System.out
                        .println("Successfully connected debugger to SQL Developer localhost:4000");
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @throws SQLException
     */
    public static void stopOracleDebugger(Connection concection) {
        // Close connection to SQL Developer listenning on localhost:4000
        if (Boolean.getBoolean("oracle.debug")) {
            try {
                if(Boolean.getBoolean("oracle.debug")){
                    CallableStatement cs=concection.prepareCall("{CALL DBMS_DEBUG_JDWP.DISCONNECT(DBMS_DEBUG_JDWP.CURRENT_SESSION_ID())}");
                    cs.execute();
                    System.out.println("Disconnecting debugger from SQL Developer localhost:4000");
                }
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

/*     */ 
/*     */   protected void closeConnection()
/*     */   {
/*     */     try
/*     */     {
/* 111 */       if ((this.mConnection != null) && (!this.mConnection.isClosed()) && (this.mDataSource != null))
/*     */       {
/* 114 */         this.mConnection.close();
/* 115 */         this.mConnection = null;
/*     */       }
/*     */     }
/*     */     catch (Exception e)
/*     */     {
/* 120 */       System.err.println("Exception when closing connection " + e.getMessage());
/*     */     }
/*     */   }
/*     */ 
/*     */   protected void closeResultSet(ResultSet result)
/*     */   {
/*     */     try
/*     */     {
/* 131 */       if (result != null)
/*     */       {
/* 133 */         result.close();
/*     */       }
/*     */     }
/*     */     catch (Exception e)
/*     */     {
/* 138 */       System.err.println("Exception when closing result set " + e.getMessage());
/*     */     }
/*     */   }
/*     */ 
/*     */   protected void closeStatement(Statement stmt)
/*     */   {
/*     */     try
/*     */     {
/* 149 */       if (stmt != null)
/*     */       {
/* 151 */         stmt.close();
/*     */       }
/*     */     }
/*     */     catch (Exception e)
/*     */     {
/* 156 */       System.err.println("Exception when closing statement " + e.getMessage());
/*     */     }
/*     */   }
/*     */ 
/*     */   public String clobToString(CLOB clob) throws SQLException
/*     */   {
/* 162 */     BufferedReader br = null;
/*     */     try
/*     */     {
/* 165 */       br = new BufferedReader(clob.getCharacterStream());
/* 166 */       char[] chars = new char[(int)clob.length()];
/* 167 */       br.read(chars);
/* 168 */       String str = new String(chars);
/*     */       return str;
/*     */     }
/*     */     catch (IOException e)
/*     */     {
/* 172 */       throw new SQLException(e.getMessage());
/*     */     }
/*     */     finally
/*     */     {
/*     */       try
/*     */       {
/* 178 */         br.close(); } catch (IOException e) {
/*     */       }
/*     */     }
/* 180 */     //throw localObject;
/*     */   }
/*     */ 
/*     */   public byte[] blobToByteArray(BLOB blob)
/*     */     throws SQLException
/*     */   {
/* 186 */     InputStream is = null;
/*     */     try
/*     */     {
/* 189 */       is = blob.getBinaryStream();
/* 190 */       byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)blob.length()];
/* 191 */       is.read(bytes);
/* 192 */       byte[] arrayOfByte1 = bytes;
/*     */       return arrayOfByte1;
/*     */     }
/*     */     catch (IOException e)
/*     */     {
/* 196 */       throw new SQLException(e.getMessage());
/*     */     }
/*     */     finally
/*     */     {
/*     */       try
/*     */       {
/* 202 */         is.close(); } catch (IOException e) {
/*     */       }
/*     */     }
/* 204 */     //throw localObject;
/*     */   }
/*     */ 
/*     */   public void updateClob(CLOB clob, String str)
/*     */     throws SQLException
/*     */   {
/* 211 */     if (str.length() < clob.length()) {
/* 212 */       clob.trim(str.length());
/*     */     }
/* 214 */     BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter(clob.getCharacterOutputStream());
/*     */     try
/*     */     {
/* 217 */       br.write(str);
/*     */     }
/*     */     catch (IOException e)
/*     */     {
/* 221 */       throw new SQLException(e.getMessage());
/*     */     }
/*     */     finally
/*     */     {
/*     */       try
/*     */       {
/* 227 */         br.flush();
/* 228 */         br.close();
/*     */       }
/*     */       catch (IOException e)
/*     */       {
/* 232 */         throw new SQLException(e.getMessage());
/*     */       }
/*     */     }
/*     */   }
/*     */ 
/*     */   public void updateBlob(BLOB blob, byte[] bytes) throws SQLException
/*     */   {
/* 239 */     if (bytes == null) {
/* 240 */       bytes = new byte[0];
/*     */     }
/*     */ 
/* 243 */     if (bytes.length < blob.length()) {
/* 244 */       blob.trim(bytes.length);
/*     */     }
/* 246 */     OutputStream os = blob.getBinaryOutputStream();
/*     */     try
/*     */     {
/* 249 */       os.write(bytes);
/*     */     }
/*     */     catch (IOException e)
/*     */     {
/* 253 */       throw new SQLException(e.getMessage());
/*     */     }
/*     */     finally
/*     */     {
/*     */       try
/*     */       {
/* 259 */         os.flush();
/* 260 */         os.close();
/*     */       }
/*     */       catch (IOException e)
/*     */       {
/* 264 */         e.printStackTrace();
/* 265 */         throw new SQLException(e.getMessage());
/*     */       }
/*     */     }
/*     */   }
/*     */ 
/*     */   protected RuntimeException handleSQLException(String sql, SQLException sqle)
/*     */   {
/* 272 */     return handleSQLException(null, sql, sqle);
/*     */   }
/*     */ 
/*     */   protected RuntimeException handleSQLException(PrimaryKey pk, String sql, SQLException sqle)
/*     */   {
/* 277 */     StringBuffer msg = new StringBuffer();
/* 278 */     if (pk != null) {
/* 279 */       msg.append(pk.toString() + ',');
/*     */     }
/* 281 */     if (sqle.getSQLState() != null) {
/* 282 */       msg.append("sqlState=" + sqle.getSQLState() + ',');
/*     */     }
/* 284 */     if (sqle.getErrorCode() != 0) {
/* 285 */       msg.append("sqlCode=" + sqle.getErrorCode());
/*     */     }
/* 287 */     this._log.error("handleSQLException", msg.toString());
/* 288 */     this._log.error("handleSQLException", sql, sqle);
/*     */ 
/* 290 */     if (sqle.getMessage() != null) {
/* 291 */       msg.append(' ' + sqle.getMessage());
/*     */     }
/* 293 */     CPException e = new CPException(msg.toString());
/*     */ 
/* 295 */     e.setStackTrace(sqle.getStackTrace());
/*     */ 
/* 297 */     return e;
/*     */   }
/*     */ 
/*     */   protected Long checkLong(long value, ResultSet rs)
/*     */     throws SQLException
/*     */   {
/* 304 */     Long obj = null;
/*     */ 
/* 306 */     if (!rs.wasNull()) {
/* 307 */       obj = new Long(value);
/*     */     }
/* 309 */     return obj;
/*     */   }
/*     */ 
/*     */   protected Integer checkInteger(int value, ResultSet rs)
/*     */     throws SQLException
/*     */   {
/* 315 */     Integer obj = null;
/*     */ 
/* 317 */     if (!rs.wasNull()) {
/* 318 */       obj = new Integer(value);
/*     */     }
/* 320 */     return obj;
/*     */   }
/*     */ 
/*     */   protected Short checkShort(short value, ResultSet rs)
/*     */     throws SQLException
/*     */   {
/* 326 */     Short obj = null;
/*     */ 
/* 328 */     if (!rs.wasNull()) {
/* 329 */       obj = new Short(value);
/*     */     }
/* 331 */     return obj;
/*     */   }
/*     */ 
/*     */   protected Boolean checkBoolean(boolean value, ResultSet rs)
/*     */     throws SQLException
/*     */   {
/* 337 */     Boolean obj = null;
/*     */ 
/* 339 */     if (!rs.wasNull()) {
/* 340 */       obj = new Boolean(value);
/*     */     }
/* 342 */     return obj;
/*     */   }
/*     */ 
/*     */   protected Integer getWrappedIntegerFromJdbc(ResultSet rs, int col) throws SQLException
/*     */   {
/* 347 */     int value = rs.getInt(col);
/* 348 */     if (!rs.wasNull()) {
/* 349 */       return new Integer(value);
/*     */     }
/* 351 */     return null;
/*     */   }
/*     */ 
/*     */   protected Short getWrappedShortFromJdbc(ResultSet rs, int col) throws SQLException {
/* 355 */     short value = rs.getShort(col);
/* 356 */     if (!rs.wasNull()) {
/* 357 */       return new Short(value);
/*     */     }
/* 359 */     return null;
/*     */   }
/*     */ 
/*     */   protected Long getWrappedLongFromJdbc(ResultSet rs, int col) throws SQLException {
/* 363 */     long value = rs.getLong(col);
/* 364 */     if (!rs.wasNull()) {
/* 365 */       return new Long(value);
/*     */     }
/* 367 */     return null;
/*     */   }
/*     */ 
/*     */   protected Boolean getWrappedBooleanFromJdbc(ResultSet rs, int col) throws SQLException {
/* 371 */     String value = rs.getString(col);
/* 372 */     if (!rs.wasNull()) {
/* 373 */       return new Boolean(value.equals("Y"));
/*     */     }
/* 375 */     return null;
/*     */   }
/*     */ 
/*     */   protected void setWrappedPrimitiveToJdbc(PreparedStatement stmt, int col, Integer o) throws SQLException
/*     */   {
/* 380 */     if (o == null)
/* 381 */       stmt.setNull(col, 2);
/*     */     else
/* 383 */       stmt.setInt(col, o.intValue());
/*     */   }
/*     */ 
/*     */   protected void setWrappedPrimitiveToJdbc(PreparedStatement stmt, int col, Short o) throws SQLException {
/* 387 */     if (o == null)
/* 388 */       stmt.setNull(col, 2);
/*     */     else
/* 390 */       stmt.setShort(col, o.shortValue());
/*     */   }
/*     */ 
/*     */   protected void setWrappedPrimitiveToJdbc(PreparedStatement stmt, int col, Long o) throws SQLException {
/* 394 */     if (o == null)
/* 395 */       stmt.setNull(col, 2);
/*     */     else
/* 397 */       stmt.setLong(col, o.longValue());
/*     */   }
/*     */ 
/*     */   protected void setWrappedPrimitiveToJdbc(PreparedStatement stmt, int col, Boolean o) throws SQLException {
/* 401 */     if (o == null)
/* 402 */       stmt.setNull(col, 1);
/*     */     else
/* 404 */       stmt.setString(col, o.booleanValue() ? "Y" : " ");
/*     */   }
/*     */ 
/*     */   public abstract String getEntityName();
/*     */ 
/*     */   protected StringTemplate getTemplate(String name)
/*     */   {
/* 417 */     StringTemplate stringTemplate = getTemplateGroup().getTemplateDefinition(name);
/*     */ 
/* 419 */     if (stringTemplate != null) {
/* 420 */       stringTemplate.reset();
/*     */     }
/* 422 */     return stringTemplate;
/*     */   }
/*     */ 
/*     */   private StringTemplateGroup getTemplateGroup()
/*     */   {
/* 431 */     String fullClassName = getClass().getName();
/* 432 */     String stringTemplateFileName = fullClassName.substring(fullClassName.lastIndexOf(46) + 1) + ".stg";
/*     */     try
/*     */     {
/* 435 */       if (this.mStringTemplateGroup == null)
/*     */       {
/* 437 */         this.mStringTemplateGroup = new StringTemplateGroup(getReader(stringTemplateFileName));
/*     */       }
/* 439 */       return this.mStringTemplateGroup;
/*     */     }
/*     */     catch (IOException e) {
/*     */     }
/* 443 */     throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to load string template group file:" + stringTemplateFileName);
/*     */   }
/*     */ 
/*     */   protected Reader getReader(String resourceName)
/*     */     throws IOException
/*     */   {
/* 457 */     InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream(resourceName);
/* 458 */     if (is != null)
/*     */     {
/* 460 */       return new InputStreamReader(is);
/*     */     }
/*     */ 
/* 465 */     File f = new File(resourceName);
/* 466 */     return new FileReader(f);
/*     */   }
/*     */ 
/*     */   public void setAllConstraintsDeferred(boolean sessionLevel)
/*     */     throws SQLException
/*     */   {
/* 478 */     PreparedStatement ps = null;
/*     */     try
/*     */     {
/* 481 */       ps = getConnection().prepareStatement(sessionLevel ? "alter session set constraints = deferred" : "set constraints all deferred");
/*     */ 
/* 484 */       ps.executeUpdate();
/*     */     }
/*     */     finally
/*     */     {
/* 488 */       closeStatement(ps);
/* 489 */       closeConnection();
/*     */     }
/*     */   }
/*     */ 
/*     */   public void setAllConstraintsImmediate(boolean sessionLevel)
/*     */     throws SQLException
/*     */   {
/* 501 */     PreparedStatement ps = null;
/*     */     try
/*     */     {
/* 504 */       ps = getConnection().prepareStatement(sessionLevel ? "alter session set constraints = immediate" : "set constraints all immediate");
/*     */ 
/* 507 */       ps.executeUpdate();
/*     */     }
/*     */     finally
/*     */     {
/* 511 */       closeStatement(ps);
/* 512 */       closeConnection();
/*     */     }
/*     */   }
/*     */ }

/* Location:           /home/oracle/coa/cp.ear/cp.ear_orginal/cp-server.jar
 * Qualified Name:     com.cedar.cp.ejb.impl.base.AbstractDAO
 * JD-Core Version:    0.6.0
 */
```

Comment: Are you use you are using Oracle?

Comment: It looks like you are using the `H2` JAR.

Comment: yes.I am using oracle database. the version is 12c. original version is oracle 6.but I am going to upgrade it to 12c.

Comment: You are presenting us with a Sql query but the error us on different layer that is JDBC. Does this query run on sqlplus? What is TO_CHAR function?

Comment: `this.mDataSource.getConnection()` <-- I propose that this is picking up the H2 JAR and not Oracle.  Check the folder containing your JDBC JARs.

Comment: as you can see, it is oracle.

Comment: This isn't at all clear to me.  Debug your connection code and see which JAR is being picked up.

Comment: Hello sir. I debug my source. it is spring-jdbc-4.2.1.release.jar.

Comment: Can you run `jar -tvf spring-jdbc-4.2.1.release.jar` on that JAR file?  What do you see inside?

Comment: Obviously this is NOT an Oracle question: if `TO_CHAR` makes it to the Oracle database server, you wouldn't get that error, since obviously Oracle does know about that function. So look for the error somewhere else, don't waste your time trying to figure out how this error is raised from the Oracle database server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TO\_CHAR function not available in H2 database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17832394/to-char-function-not-available-in-h2-database)

Comment: This is out put of the command. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzEc51fOoK5kVjItSjBJNGNlWW8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: If you getting an `org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException` you are most definitely **not** using Oracle.

Answer (score 4):

Your exception seems to indicate that you are using the `H2` JDBC JAR, not Oracle.  Include the Oracle JDBC JAR and then connect via this:

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
Connection connection = null;
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:SID","username","password");
connection.close();
```

Here is link where you can download the `12c` driver:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/jdbc-drivers-12c-download-1958347.html

Comment: I am using oracle database and source code is stmt = this.mDataSource.getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);stmt.setFetchSize(500);resultset = stmt.executeQuery()

Comment: and I am using ojbdc6.jar for jdcb driver.

Comment: You should update your question to show your connection code.

Comment: @美丽美丽花 No, you are not using Oracle otherwise you wouldn't get that exception.